# how to write data TINYXML2 on IOS

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

My test.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PLAY SYSTEM "play.dtd">            
<data>
    <CurrentLevel>5</CurrentLevel>
    <BestScoreLV1>1</BestScoreLV1>
    <BestScoreLV2>2</BestScoreLV2>
</data>
<dict/>
```

My Code here:

```
std::string fullPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathFromRelativePath("text.xml");
tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;

doc.LoadFile(fullPath.c_str());

tinyxml2::XMLElement* ele =  doc.FirstChildElement("data")->FirstChildElement("BestScoreLV2")->ToElement();
ele->SetAttribute("value", 10);
doc.SaveFile(fullPath.c_str());

const char* title1 =  doc.FirstChildElement("data")->FirstChildElement("BestScoreLV2")->GetText();
int level1  = atoi(title1);
CCLOG("result is: %d",level1);
```

But value of BestScoreLV2 when output is also 2. How can I change and write data to XML?

Answer (score 0):

In TinyXML2 text is represented by `XMLText` class which is child of `XMLNode` class.
`XMLNode` have methods `Value()` and `SetValue()` which have different meanings for different XML nodes.
For text nodes `Value()` read node's text and `SetValue()` write it.
So you need code like this:

```
tinyxml2::XMLNode* value = doc.FirstChildElement("data")->
    FirstChildElement("BestScoreLV2")->FirstChild();
value->SetValue("10");
```

The first child of `BestScoreLV2` element is `XMLText` with value `2`. You change this value to `10` by calling `SetValue(10)`.